# Zend_Navigation add class to active link

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

How can I add a class to the active navigation link? If a link points to URI /index/index and the request URI is also /index/index, I would like the link to have class, for example:

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="/index/index">Index</a>
</li>
```

This is how I am initializing navigation in the bootstrap:

```
protected function _initNavigation()
{
$navigation = new Zend_Navigation($this->getOption('navigation'));
$this->view->navigation($navigation);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

I have solved this by writing a controller plugin:

```
<?php
class My_Controller_Plugin_PrepareNavigation extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('ViewRenderer');
        $viewRenderer->initView();
        $view = $viewRenderer->view;

        $container = new Zend_Navigation(Zend_Registry::get('configuration')->navigation);
        foreach ($container->getPages() as $page) {
            $uri = $page->getHref();
            if ($uri === $request->getRequestUri()) {
                $page->setClass('active');
            }
        }
        $view->navigation($container);
    }
}
```

Comment: The optimal solution would be create your own partial to render the menu and there handle the conditions. The above approach needs to walk all the elements twice (once in controller, second during the rendering).

Answer (score 0):

This is how to create a navigation() in a layout() with zend frameworks using Application.
Well, at least one way of doing it. the CSS class is set on the

put this into the Bootstrap.php file:

```
protected function _initNavigation() 
{
     $this->bootstrap('layout');
     $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
     $view = $layout->getView();        
     include APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts/menu.phtml';      
     $view->navigation($container);
}
```

This allows you to create an array for a menu in the file menu.phtml, so that you can still maintain the active class on the current link. For some strange reason, if you use this you must include the controller property in the array to get the CSS active class on the current link.

put something like this into the /layouts/scripts/menu.phtml file:

```
$container = new Zend_Navigation(array(
array(
    'label' => 'HOME',
    'id' => 'tasks',
    'uri'=>'/',
    'controller' => 'Index'
),
array(
    'label' => 'Contact',
    'uri' => 'contact',
    'controller' => 'Contact'
), 

.... more code here ...
```

put this into the layout.phtml file:

```
$options = array('ulClass' => 'menu');
```